# Is it okay to use “doesn’t” twice in one sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, negation, repetition

I wonder if it's okay to use "doesn't" twice in one sentece.

**Example**

> I think that she **doesn't** do something and it **doesn't** something...

Should I split it or it's completely correct? I mean two unrelated piece of information that I want to negate in one sentence.

Comment: Could you give an actual sentence with real words so that we can see the real context? Thanks. . Also, please don't use 'sth'. It is used in some EFL dictionaries but it is not a recognised abbreviation among native speakers.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Sentence provided by @Cole  is a good example. Thank you for your helpful advice about `something`.

Comment: “Should I split it…” — You already _have_ split it. ‘And’ is a coordinating conjunction that can (as here) link entire main clauses. In this use, it is structurally equivalent to a full stop in that it separates the two clauses completely (while still keeping them semantically connected to each other). So “She doesn’t have a car, and I don’t have a dog” is just as much split up as “She doesn’t have a car. I don’t have a dog”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's grammatically fine to use two "doesn't" in the same sentence so long as they don't form a double negative. Without the full context of your sentence it's hard to understand what "it's" referring to in this sentence, but there's nothing that says you can't use two contractions in the same complex or simple sentence.

If you're attempting to say something like this:

> I think that she doesn't do jumping jacks and it doesn't matter to me whether she does jumping jacks or not.

You're conveying two separate ideas and the doesn't is working in two different ways so it's perfectly fine.

If you're talking about whether or not it's "okay" as in, whether or not it's weak writing, that's a completely different subject that's largely subjective and dependent on the full context of your sentence.

Comment: Thank you. Of course I wasn't talking about double negative - just 2 separate ideas.

Comment: Then you should be fine grammatically as long as they are negating two separate ideas. You might ask yourself whether or not you want to, style wise, use two "doesn't" however.

Comment: He doesn't drink, doesn't cuss, doesn't steal, doesn't chase after women, doesn't do drugs, doesn't sin. For Goodness sake, what **does** he do?

Comment: I see what you did there :P.